# Custom Plugin interfering with the Orders "PHP"

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have this custom made plugin that i wanted to use in my wordpress, and when i activate it, it starts to interfere with the Orders backend, that means whenever i want to see what Product did the customer order, i only get to see the price but the product's image isnt showing in Woocommerce > Orders > Click on the order.

```
<?php

function sms_notif_pending($order_id) {
    // error_log("$order_id set to PENDING", 0);
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'pending');
}

function sms_notif_failed($order_id) {
    // error_log("$order_id set to FAILED", 0);
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'failed');
}

function sms_notif_hold($order_id) {
    // error_log("$order_id set to ON HOLD", 0);
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'hold');
}

function sms_notif_processing($order_id) {
    //  error_log("$order_id set to PROCESSING", 0);
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'processing');
}

function sms_notif_completed($order_id) {
    //error_log("$order_id set to COMPLETED", 0);$
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'completed');
}

function sms_notif_refunded($order_id) {
    // error_log("$order_id set to REFUNDED", 0);
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'refunded');
}

function sms_notif_cancelled($order_id) {
    // error_log("$order_id set to CANCELLED", 0);
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'cancelled');
}

function sms_notif_at_delivery($order_id) {
    // error_log("$order_id set to CANCELLED", 0);
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'at_delivery');
}


function sms_notif_at_reserved($order_id) {
    // error_log("$order_id set to CANCELLED", 0);
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'at_reserved');
}



function sms_notif_at_fitting($order_id) {
    // error_log("$order_id set to CANCELLED", 0);
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'at_fitting');
}


function sms_notif_shipping_progress($order_id) {
    // error_log("$order_id set to CANCELLED", 0);
    sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, 'shipping_progress');
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'sms_notif_pending');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending', 'sms_notif_pending');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed', 'sms_notif_failed');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'sms_notif_hold');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'sms_notif_processing');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'sms_notif_completed');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_refunded', 'sms_notif_refunded');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', 'sms_notif_cancelled');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_at-delivery', 'sms_notif_at_delivery');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_at-reserved', 'sms_notif_at_reserved');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_at-fitting', 'sms_notif_at_fitting');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_shipping-progress', 'sms_notif_shipping_progress');

function sms_notif_order_status_updated($order_id, $status) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );


    $billing_phone = (int)$order->get_billing_phone();
    $shipping_phone = (int)get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_phone', true );

    if (!$billing_phone && $shipping_phone) {
        $billing_phone = $shipping_phone;
    }

    if ($billing_phone) {
        switch ($status) {
            case 'pending':
                $message = "Bonjour, merci pour votre achat d'un montant de [ " . $order->get_total() . " TND ] auprès de ... Afficher la commande (#" . $order_id . ") : " . home_url() . "/mon-compte/voir-commande/" . $order_id . "/";
                break;

            case 'at_delivery':
                $message = "Bonjour, votre commande (#" . $order_id . ") est chez ..., vous recevez votre colis dans les prochaine 48h. Bonne journée";
                break;

            case 'shipping_progress':
                $message = "Bonjour, votre commande (#" . $order_id . ") est en cours de livraison, restez joignable. Bonne journée";
                break;

            case 'completed':
                $message = "Félicitations vous avez reçu votre commande (#" . $order_id . "), vous trouverez les conditions de retour et échange avec votre bon de livraison. Merci d'avoir passé vos achats sur ... A très bien tôt";
                break;
            
            default:
                return;
                break;
        }
        if($status!="at_fitting"&&$status!="at_reserved")
        $res = bulksms_send_message($billing_phone, $message);
        // echo '<pre>'; var_dump($res);
        // die();
    }
}

function bulksms_send_message($phone_number, $message) {
    $phone_number = sms_notif_filter_phone($phone_number);
    if (!$phone_number) {
        return;
    }
    $params = [
        'key'  => '...',
        'fct' => 'sms',
        'sender' => '...',
        'mobile' => '216' . $phone_number,
        'sms' => $message,
        'date' => date('d/m/Y'),
        'heure' => date('H:i'),
    ];
    $params_string = '';
    foreach($params as $key => $val) {
        $params_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($val) . '&';
    }
    $url = 'https://bulksms.bipsms.tn/Api/Api.aspx' . '?' . $params_string;

    return Requests::get($url);
}

function sms_notif_filter_phone($phone_number) {
    $phone_number = (int)$phone_number;

    if (strpos($phone_number, '216') === 0) {
        $phone_number = (int)substr($phone_number, 3, strlen($phone_number) - 3);
    }

    if (strpos($phone_number, '+216') === 0) {
        $phone_number = (int)substr($phone_number, 4, strlen($phone_number) - 3);
    }

    if (strlen($phone_number) === 8) {
        return $phone_number;
    }

    return null;

}


add_action( 'woocommerce_after_register_post_type', 'sms_notif_woocommerce_init', 10, 1 );

function sms_notif_woocommerce_init() {
    if (isset($_GET['sms_notif_order_status_updated'])) {
        sms_notif_order_status_updated(9469, 'completed');
    }
}



function wc_register_post_statuses() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-at-delivery', array(
        'label' => _x( 'Chez Livreur', 'WooCommerce Order status', '...' ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop( 'Chez livreur (%s)', 'Chez livreur (%s)', '...' )
    ) );
        register_post_status( 'wc-at-reserved', array(
        'label' => _x( 'Reservée', 'WooCommerce Order status', '...' ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop( 'Reservée (%s)', 'Reservée (%s)', '...' )
    ) );

    register_post_status( 'wc-at-fitting', array(
        'label' => _x( 'Essayage', 'WooCommerce Order status', '...' ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop( 'Essayage (%s)', 'Essayage (%s)', '...' )
    ) );
    
    
    register_post_status( 'wc-shipping-progress', array(
        'label' => _x( 'En cours de livraison', 'WooCommerce Order status', '...' ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop( 'En cours de livraison (%s)', 'En cours de livraison (%s)', '...' )
    ) );



    // add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address', 'filter_woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address', 99, 3);
}
add_filter( 'init', 'wc_register_post_statuses');



function wc_add_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-at-delivery'] = _x( 'Chez Livreur', 'WooCommerce Order status', '...' );
    $order_statuses['wc-at-reserved'] = _x( 'Reservée', 'WooCommerce Order status', '...' );
    $order_statuses['wc-at-fitting'] = _x( 'Essayage', 'WooCommerce Order status', '...' );
    $order_statuses['wc-shipping-progress'] = _x( 'En cours de livraison', 'WooCommerce Order status', '...' );
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wc_add_order_statuses' );




function filter_woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address_testtest( $array, $order ) {
    $array = [
        'x' => $order->get_billing_phone(),
    ];
    return $array;
}


function filter_woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address( $array, $order ) {
    if (isset($_GET['bewpi_action']) && $order) {
        $array['company'] = $array['company'] . "\n" . $order->get_billing_phone();
    }
    return $array;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address', 'filter_woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address', 10, 3 ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'filter_woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address', 10, 3 );
```

everything else is working fine, only this problem that i have...
if anyone need some other details, i'll gladly post them here.

Comment: What error shows for the image? Remove your key from the parameters. This is sensitive information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mainul, the error is that the image doesn't show at all when this plugin is activated, only the price and customer informations are showing. but when i deactivate the plugin, the order's photo ( or article ) start showing again.
PS: key removed

Comment: Comment out **all** of your `add_filter` and `add_action`, which should hopefully make things work again. Then, one by one, uncomment each and test. This should help you narrow things down a bit.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you for the Answer! if you can give me an exemple from the code that i shared, it would be a great help!

Comment: You can comment an action out by putting two forward slashes in front of it, `//add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'sms_notif_pending');`

Comment: @ChrisHaas i will be trying that now, and i'll leave a message again about how it went

Comment: thank you for your help @ChrisHaas , the problem got fixed after i commented out //add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'sms_notif_pending');